# Change speed and duplex on startup

Tags: networking

I have an old computer (6 years, I think) that mounts a jmicron ethernet card.

Firstly it didn't work at all. Investigating, I discovered that it was down, but it didn't took an IP by itself. After a while asking google about it, the solution is changing the speed and duplex to 100Mbps and full, that is the only mode that the adapter accepts for some reason, think the driver is kinda broken.

The problem is everytime I reboot the system, obviously the changes aren't saved and I have to manually set the speed and duplex again to get internet working, and it's a problem since I manage this computer by SSH, so I need the internet to get up on startup automatically.

How can I run a couple of commands on startup? Think that things have changed a bit with bionic beaver, and I'm kinda lost.

PC info:
OS: Ubuntu Server 18.04 (without X)

Commands:

```
ethtool -s enp3s0 speed 1000 duplex full
ethtool -s enp3s0 speed 100 duplex full
ifdown enp3s0
ifup enp3s0
```

(need to set first 1000 and then 100, if not, it doesnt work)

lshw -c network result:

```
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 03
   serial: f4:6d:04:1e:bd:42
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msix msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=jme driverversion=1.0.8 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:26 memory:fbffc000-fbffffff ioport:ec00(size=128) ioport:e800(size=256)
```

If you need some more info, just tell me.
Thanks! ^^

Answer (score 0):

K, I've found how to do it.

I just created the rc.local script with the commands above, disabled the waiting service with:

```
systemctl disable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Because it was waiting like 5 mins to have an internet source working, and changed /etc/network/interfaces to:

```
allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

So it wasn't trying to set up the interface for that 5 mins.

Now it works perfectly. I was kinda confused because rc.local doesn't exist by default.